# How to change the video Media Gallery featured thumbnails?

Tags: wordpress

I have video page which display all video i uploaded using rtmedia shortcode. How to change the thumbnail into a specific image just like the video? Something like featured image.

======================================================================
[image]

======================================================================

I want the real picture display as like on the video.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: check it here http://docs.rtcamp.com/rtmedia/admin/regenerate-video-thumbnails/, search with google before post the question

Answer (score 0):

You can go for encoding service subscription.

It will generate thumbnails for video and by editing video you can select the thumbnail you want.

Also, you will also be able to upload and encode videos other than .mp4 - default supported format.

Reference link  http://docs.rtcamp.com/rtmedia/getting-started/audio-video-encoding/

Thanks.